# How do I find a LaTeX font with an upper-case cursive letter Z?

Tags: fonts, symbols

I cannot seem to figure out how to make an upper-case, cursive letter Z, like the one on the left in [this picture](http://www.janbrett.com/alphabet/cursive_alphabet_z_zebra.htm). By using a french cursive environment, I can get the lower-case z, but the upper-case Z is not what I am looking for. Anyone know how to get LaTeX to make this font/symbol?

Comment: This is really a question of having the correct font: not exactly a TeX question.

Comment: @Joseph: Aren't we usually accepting questions asking for a TeX font with a specific symbol?

Comment: If this is a font question, try [WhatTheFont?](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/).  If this is a symbol question, try [Detexify](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16690/cursive-font-question)

Comment: @Caramdir: my bad, I prematurely voted to close thinking it was a font question.  Reading it again I considered it might be a symbol question.

Comment: @Caramdir: I didn't vote to close, did I :-) To me, this looks like a 'teaching' font question (the example looks like the sort of thing you'd see in a handwriting style book). However, I may be wrong.

Comment: I tried Detexify first with no luck!

Comment: Did my answer help with your question? If so, please consider accepting it by clicking the the check mark underneath its vote count. If not, please specify what aspect it's lacking to fulfill your needs.

Answer (score 7):

You can find a number of font alternatives that get pretty close to your sample at [the LaTeX Font Catalogue, Calligraphical and Handwritten Fonts](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/calligraphicalfonts.html). Here are some options (although some are of questionable typographically technical quality, i.e. not vectorized fonts that look pixel-y):

[image: Z in different fonts]

Lukas Svatba has even more options. For information on how to implement a particular font, see the respective page in the Font Catalogue.